# How to implement the REAL cast intrinsic for custom data type in Fortran

Tags: casting, fortran, overloading, fortran90, custom-data-type

I have been looking around the internet for a solution to this problem, but I have to admit I am completely stuck.

What I have is a derived data type

```
TYPE :: MyType
    REAL(KIND=MY_REAL_KIND) :: real_val
    INTEGER :: int_val
END TYPE
```

I am overloading operators and intrinsic functions to work with it.
I need to overload the REAL cast to work with this type, so that when is called it gives back the real_val member. So fa so good:

```
 FUNCTION real_mytype (a) RESULT (x)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    TYPE(MyType), INTENT(IN) :: a
    REAL(KIND=MY_REAL_KIND) :: x
    # Take advantage of the overloaded (=) operator
    x = a
END FUNCTION real_mytype
```

But then I need to perform a cast with specified precision, let's say like

```
INTEGER, PUBLIC, PARAMETER :: sp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND( 6, 37)
INTEGER, PUBLIC, PARAMETER :: dp = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(12,307)
TYPE(MyType) :: a
call external_function_that_I_cant_change(REAL(a, sp))
call second_external_function_that_I_cant_change(REAL(a, dp))
```

I don't know how to write such interface, because the type of the return value (double real or single real) will depend on the value of the INTEGER input parameter (sp or dp) and not on its type, which is kind of forbidden in Fortran. The following does simply not make sense:

```
FUNCTION real_mytype_1d (a, p) RESULT (x)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    TYPE(MyType),  INTENT(IN) :: a
    INTEGER                   :: p
    REAL(KIND=something_that_depends_on_p)  :: x
    x = a
END FUNCTION real_mytype_1d
```

I already took a look at the transfer function like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48326191/a-fortran-function-subroutine-that-could-return-either-a-real-an-integer-or-a-s) but I was not able to figure out a solution (the type of return val there depends on the mold type).

Any suggestion?

Comment: The question you link to has an answer which (correctly) says that what you want to do isn't possible. You can use the type (like `real(a,0._dp)` which is the mold idea), but not the value. Intrinsic procedures are allowed to behave very differently from non-intrinsic ones.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply! If I understand correctly you are saying that I can not reproduce the behavior of an Intrinsic procedure merely with an overload, so that I can not create a module procedure for REAL function that behaves exactly like the intrinsic Fortran one?

Comment: You can recreate the behaviour of some (/many/most) intrinsics, but not all. `real` being one clear case, because: (non-intrinsic) generic disambiguation cannot come through an argument value; a dummy argument's value can't appear in a constant expression; the value _can_ be used to control flow resulting in different polymorphic allocation of function result, but such a function result is subject to numerous restrictions in use. Simply, intrinsics aren't subject to the same rules we are (see "how do we implement `trim` in Forttan 77?").

Comment: Many thanks, this clears all the doubts I had. I will pass a real with the correct type then!